# Updating Relational Tables using merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a hypothetical example, say I have two tables: **FARM** and **FRUIT**

FARM is organized like:

```
FARM_ID    Size    
1          50      
2          100
3          200
...
```

and FRUIT is organized like:

```
Reference_ID    FRUIT
 1              Banana
 1              Grape
 1              Orange
 2              Banana
 2              Strawberry
```

FRUIT table is created from taking a parameter @fruit from excel which is a delimited string using '/'.

For example, @fruit = 'Banana/Grape/Orange'

And using a statement like:

```
INSERT INTO FRUIT(
Fruit,
Reference_ID,
)

SELECT Fruit, Scope_IDENTITY() from split_string(@fruit, '/')
```

Where split_string is a function.

My goal is to check for updates. I want to take in a Farm_ID and @fruit and check to see if any changes have been made to the fruit.

1) If the values haven't changed, dont do anything

2) If a new fruit was added, add it to the FRUIT table with the farm_ID

3) If there is a fruit in the FRUIT table that does not correspond to the new delimited list for the respectful FARM_ID, remove it from the FRUIT table.

I think a Merge statement would probably work but open to suggestions. Let me know if anything is unclear. Thank you

EDIT

Im fairly new to SQL but have tried using a merge...

```
Declare @foo tinyint
Merge Fruit as Target
Using (Select Fruit , @workingID From split_string(@fruit, '/') As source      (fruit, ID)
--@workingID is just a way to get the ID from other parts of the sproc.
ON (TARGET.fruit = source.fruit)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
SET @foo = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT INTO FRUIT(
Reference_ID,
Fruit
)
VALUES(
```

Then I am a bit stuck on how to get unique, new values

Comment: @ajeh, see edits. hopefully helps

Answer (score 0):

Any way your input contains the new fruit list against the farm id. So better option is to delete the existing and insert the new list of fruit against the farmid.

Sample script is given below.

```
   --loading the input to temp table
    SELECT Fruit,@referenceid ReferenceId -- farmid corresponding tithe fruit list
      INTO #temp
   FROM Split_string(@fruit,'/')

   -- delete the existing data against the given farmid
  DELETE FROM fruit f
  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM #temp t 
         WHERE f.Reference_id=t.ReferenceId)

    -- insert the new list
    INSERT INTO fruit 
    SELECT fruit,referenceId
    FROM #temp
```

Comment: would this be better then using a merge and when matched, when not matched by source, when not matched by target?